# open new gnome terminal window from python in a specific directory or with "less" command

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have a GUI application from which I want to open new terminal windows:

1. open new terminal in specific directory ('`cd /home/abc/`').
2. open a text file with 'less' command ('`less /home/abc/def.txt`').

tried 1 with:

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('gnome-terminal -x tcsh -c "cd /home/abc/"'))
```

problem: it opens a new terminal window and closes it immediately

tried 2 with:

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('gnome-terminal -x tcsh -c "less /abc/def.txt"'))
```

problem: opens the file with less command as wanted, but closes the terminal window when "`q`" is pressed to exit "`less`".

Is there any way to make the new terminal windows stay alive?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a solution for your first problem. I tested it on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS:

```
import subprocess    
cmd = "gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/begueradj/Desktop"
subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True)
```

Comment: the code you provided to open in specific dir works. regarding 'less', i want a new terminal window to be opened with 'less' on specific file. when i press 'q' i want the window to stay open, but outside of 'less'. just terminal window in the directory of the previously seen file. the code you provided with 'less' opens the less in the same terminal, not new window. the code i wrote above makes the window to close completely (not only get out of 'less') when 'q' is pressed.